# Must declare the scalar variable - Delete Command

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net

When I run this code I get the code, I get the error Must declare the scalar variable. If I use just Vendor and remove the delete parameters, it works fine, but only on Vendor. The delete process is working on a GridView with auto generated columns but the delete button. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                OnClientClick="return isDelete();">Delete
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestAdamConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TestRedo]" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TestRedo] WHERE [Vendor] = @Vendor AND [Expiration] = @Expiration AND [ActionReq] = @ActionReq">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Expiration" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ActionReq"/>
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: look at your `DeleteParameters` this looks pretty obvious.. here where are you defining your `Vendor`
`<DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Expiration" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ActionReq"/>
    </DeleteParameters>`

Comment: I don't need to declare the parameters if I am just using Vendor. For whatever reason it just works, but it doesn't seem to accept the parameters because it can't find them.

Comment: I think you are incorrect.. why don't you change the Delete Parameter to Call a Stored Procedure and then what you are say would be valid.. look at MSDN Documentation personally I would not use SqlDataSource you could have had this re-written using a stored procedure 10 times over by now

Comment: How do I add that in? I have the procedure made, but I don't know how to use it in the DeleteCommand property field.

Comment: do you know how to use google do google search come on now.. I am not going to do your work for you.. sorry .. good day